# MongoDB with Node, set starting point and select finite reverse number of records

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongo as my data store for a list of messages sent. Each message has an `id` and what I would like to be able to do (as efficiently as possible) is return `n` number of results starting before a supplied `id` going in reverse.

So, for example, with a function call like:

```
getHistory(start, count)
```

I could supply:

```
getHistory("a123", 10)
```

Which would return 10 records prior to the record with 'id="a123"`. Trick is the ID's are GUID and so I can't just increment backward based on that.

This is what I have so far and it's not starting in the correct position:

```
var cursor = collection.find({id: id}).sort({timestamp: -1}).limit(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but something along the following lines should work (in mongoose):

```
collection.find({_id: {$lt: start}}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(10);
```

This should find all elements before the start id, reverse the order and get the first 10. In other words the last 10 before start.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I was close but seeing your example helped me fine-tune and get it working.